# How do you make a link_to text clickable to activate a Boostrap collapsible?

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

I have this code for a collapsible header text and a caret besides it which  collapses/uncollapses a `div` .

```
<span><strong>"Weekly"</strong></span> <a class="caret" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#weekly" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="weekly"></a>

<div class="collapse overflow-hidden" id="weekly">
  # Collapsible content
</div>
```

I want to make the header text next to the caret clickable too, to give the user a larger area to click on that will collapse/uncollapse the corresponding `div`.

I've tried wrapping the `span` and `a` tags inside a `link_to` with unsatisfying results (the text links to the anchor that represents the `id` of the `div` to be uncollapsed).

What would be the correct way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it clickable if you put everything in a button in the top container.

Example :

```
<a class="caret" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#weekly" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="weekly">
    <span><strong>"Weekly"</strong></span> 
</a>
```